# EMAX ESC Simon Series with arduino

Tags: arduino, brushless-motor, esc

I want to control a brushless motor with the "EMAX Simon Series 30amp ESC" and Arduino (Leonardo) board. I am really confused how to do that. I can't understand which beep sounds mean what. I have tested many code examples but they weren't useful.

Comment: Hi Mohsenadc. Welcome to SE Robotics. Which beep sounds are you referring to? Can you edit your question to include some code that you have tried? Also, can you provide a schematic diagram of your circuit, in your question? Thanks. You may want to take a [tour](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site and to [see how to best ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When say you say you "want to control a brushless motor with [a] ESC ... and Arduino", do you mean:

Do you want the Arduino to act like the RC receiver in the airplane in the air and make the propeller spin slow, stop, fast, etc.? Or,

Do you want the Arduino to act like a person changing settings in the ESC using a programming card on the ground?

### In the air

In the air, the 3 wire cable between the RC receiver and the ESC carries the so-called ["RC PWM signals"](http://www.opencircuits.com/Servo_control).
The RC receiver sends exactly the same kind of signals to RC servos.
The ESC neither knows nor cares where these signals come from -- the RC receiver, the Arduino PWM (using the [Arduino Servo library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Servo)), the [Arduino Software Servo library](http://playground.arduino.cc/ComponentLib/Servo) ( periodically calling refresh() in the main loop() ), or some other source.

### On the ground

The "beep sounds" are really only useful when changing the settings in the ESC on the ground, perhaps with a programming card.
To learn what the "beep sounds mean", see the user manual ["EMAX User Instruction for SimonK Series ESC"](http://yinyanmodel.com/EMAX%20User%20Instruction%20for%20Simonk%20Series%20ESC.pdf).

Normally this is a one-time setup, so most people do this once manually on the ground.